# How to calculate shipping cost based on Woocommerce booking time slots?

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I have a woocommerce shop with the woocommerce booking system. At my website, you can book meal deliveries based on time slots. I used the booking system because some meals are available some days. And, you can book meals on multiple days in one order.

My problem is that I want to apply a fixed shipping cost (3,5euros) based on deliveries/time slots. I can’t group meals of the same delivery in one order.

My question is : is there a way to make a php script to calculate shipping cost based on delivery time slots?

[My current cart page and what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GS73.png)

currently, i use this calculation method on woocommerce settings : 3,5 * [qty]

The problem in my case is that don't want to charge multiple times for the same delivery.

Thank you!